# Easiest way to get Compass/Sass running on OSX

Tags: installation, sass, configure, compass-sass

I first had to follow the [instructions here](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard) to make sure that I had Ruby and Gems installed.  Then I installed compass using Gems.

Then I tried to run compass and had some errors...

> "Warning: Unable to load CarbonCore.
>   FSEvents will be unavailable compass"

I found a solution [here](http://groups.google.com/group/compass-users/browse_thread/thread/df7d9d0da9ec1eb1?pli=1), but it required me to install RVM via gems first and then following the instructions in the link above.

Is there an easier way to setup/run compass/sass on OSX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is described in the [compass issue tracker](http://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/issue/98). It's not a showtopper because it falls back to another (less efficient) method of watching for file changes that doesn't depend of fsevents. Still, it would be nice to fix, right?

Since you compiled your own version of ruby, you need to enable shared libraries for it as well. This is described on the [rubycocoa getting started page](http://rubycocoa.sourceforge.net/GettingStarted).

More details can be found in [this google groups discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/compass-users/browse_thread/thread/df7d9d0da9ec1eb1?pli=1), particularly the advice from Brandon Mathis.

Comment: Right, duh. Most rubyists like to use RVM (because it makes installing large groups of gems easier to manage) but if you're just needing it for compass it's not really necessary. But it's not hard to do; you could consider that option.

Answer (score 0):

Installing last version of Compass gem (0.11.5) seems to solve the problem:

`gem install compass`

Answer (score -7):

You have to update your gems:

> sudo gem update –system

Comment: No. Not relevant. The problem is with rubycocoa, not rubygems.